# What is the unbalanced Mach-Zehnder interferometer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interference, interferometry

I read about unbalanced Mach-Zehnder interferometers in investigating the time-energy entanglement. I wanted to know what is it. and what is its purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: The beam splitter is not 50/50.

Answer (score 0):

In time energy entanglement we need two-photon one short and one long in each unbalanced Michelson interferometer. To confirm that two-photon short and long do not interfere we need to have a path length difference of short and long arm much greater than the coherence length of the incoming photon in this case it is signal and idler. This is the reason we need an unbalanced Michelson interferometer.